# I'm new on prolog and lm trying to solve this

Tags: prolog, logic

How to define a list using Prolog predicate `is_repeated(X)` such that the result of any list is `true` if it contains duplicated elements.

Comment: You need to make an attempt, show your code, and explain specifically where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is odd to say "is_repeated(X) such that the result of any list is true if it contains duplicated elements." You would say "`is_repeated(List)` holds if `List` contains duplicated elements." The parts you need from the parts bin to solve this are either recursion and `member/2` or `memberchk/2`, or `select/3` without explicit recursion, but let's talk about Prolog programming in general instead. Because I think Prolog is really neat, and the essence of what makes Prolog neat is that you can take a stupid problem like this and just sort of translate the problem statement into Prolog code without really having to tell Prolog how to do the work.

For instance, suppose your query were something like, "only_evens(List) holds if List only contains even numbers." Well, suppose I have `even/1` that is true if its argument is even. Then `forall(member(X, List), even(X))` would be a straightforward translation. It would be even more obvious if we first translated the question into a logical form: ∀x∊L, even(x). Now the relationship between ∀x∊L, F(x) and `forall(member(X, L), F(X))` should be obvious.

So the real question you should ask yourself is, what is a logical formulation of the question? I imagine it would sound something like this: suppose L is an element X prepended to the list L'. If X occurs in L', then L contains duplicates. This is a nice, efficient way to solve the problem. Now can you translate that to Prolog?